# jQuery function behavior on Chrome and IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this function that can be seen how it works on this example.

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/74/

This function work great on fiddle example but if I want to add that function from fiddle example from above the behavior is different on my project and I don't understand why because I verified the css and seems to be ok.
That function it helps me to have hover on mouse over and focus on click on two tables  displayed inline and to calculate td height when the description is higher and is displayed in the same td on multiple rows. On IE 8 and Chrome it is worse.

This is my project where I need to integrate that function, major delay is at lines 14-15 from table: http://mainpage.ueuo.com

Thank you.

Comment: in my browser the table rows are bigger because they are not wide enough to hold all 5 images for the links. Also, the last two are in the code but the images don't show for them. They are "delete" and "add". Widen the table to accommodate the images, or remove them if they are not needed. edit: it also appears that the implementation of the code to set the heights is slightly off on your actual site. it's 1 off on the far right column. For instance, the height for row 1 is getting applied to row 2 on the far right table, and so on.

Comment: http://mainpage.ueuo.com is empty